# windows 7 home premium - update to professionel

Tags: windows-7

I bought a new notebook that came with Win7 Home Premium.
I know want to sell my home premium license and buy a profesionell one.
Is it possible to just change the key in my current running and ready-configuerd win7 home premium, or do I need ti reinstall the system?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your licence is in all probability an OEM Licence, this means that it's tied to *Your* laptop only and it's illegal to sell it.

Comment: In germany it isn't...

Comment: Is there really that much of a cost difference between selling your Home Premium and buying a Pro versus the cost of the Upgrade? Especially when you factor in the ease of Windows Anytime Upgrade.

Comment: The problem is that the upgrade costs about 200$ over the windows anytime upgrade. But I could buy a full version for about 100$ in a shop.
So I would have e full version of Home Premium and Professionel...
Over the anytime upgrade I pay double and then I have only one license.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Windows Anytime Upgrade](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Windows-Windows-7/category/102?FILTER_SW_WINDOWS_EDITIONS=FV_WAU&FILTER_SW_WINDOWS_TYPE=FV_WAU&WT.mc_id=winonlinetest_shop3_WAU_r2) - no need to reinstall

Answer (score 0):

You can just do an upgrade, you can keep all your settings and programs.
All you need is the new license key and to follow the steps in Windows Anytime Upgrade.

On your PC, open Windows Anytime Upgrade (click the Start button, type Windows Anytime Upgrade into the search box, and then click Windows Anytime Upgrade in the list of results

Follow the instructions on the screen that come with your upgrade key

Source:http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/anytime-upgrade.aspx

Comment: I can buy the license somewhere and do the update via windows anytime upgrade, right?
I dont't want to buy it about the anytime upgrade because its, ähm, a little expensive ;)

Comment: Ah and another question, sorry.
I want to buy a full version of windows 7 profesionel - not an upgrade (because I want to sell the other key). Is it also possible to use a full version key with the anytime upgrade?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you can do it via anytiime upgrade with a full key sorry. You can certainally do an upgrade installation booting from the CD at startup.

Comment: @ben - If you buy an _upgrade_ version, it becomes tied to the old version. What you want (and need) is a retail version, which has it's own key, and is transferable. I don't know if you'll need to re-install or can just enter the key, but I suspect you'll need to re-install.